# TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len() in Objective function nonlinear optimization Gekko

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror, nonlinear-optimization, maximize, gekko

I am to maximize my non-linear function and trying to do that with GEKKO

```
m=GEKKO()
x=m.Var(value=1,lb=0, ub=50)
y=m.Var(value=1, lb=0, ub=50)
m.Equation(puree*x+cutlet*y==1500)
m.Obj(-min(x,y))
m.solve(disp=False)
x.value
y.value
```

but I get  `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()` in this string `m.Obj(-min(x,y))` and I don't know what to change to make it work...

Comment: I don't know much about GEKKO, but from your error message, it looks like
 `m.Obj(-min(x,y))` 
expects that x & y are lists not integers.  Check the documentation for GEKKO to be sure.  If that is the case try
 `m.Obj(-min([x],[y]))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `x` and `y` are specific Gekko variable types, even though when you display them they display as integers.  There is no min function defined on that specific type.  So when you call `min`, the Python builtin `min` function depends on `len`, and the Gekko specific `len` function takes as its argument the value of the variable, so effectively `min` calls `len(x.value)`, which does not work because `x.value` is an int (equivalently for `y`).  If you want to set your objective function to be some function of `x` and `y`, then you need to do it as such:

```
m.Obj(<f(x,y)>)
```

and Gekko will try to minimize `f`.  So if you just want to minimize `x+y`, then all you need is `m.Obj(x+y)`.

Comment: U(x,y)=min(x,y) is my initial utility function to maximize..I've tried `m.Obj(<f(x,y)>)` but it yields `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Then given what it looks like your equality constraint is, you need the `min2` function, i.e. `m.Obj(-m.min2(x,y))`.

Answer (score 1):

As tclarke13 correctly points out, you need to use the `m.min2()` or `m.min3()` functions to create a continuously differentiable version of the minimum function.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m=GEKKO()
x,y = m.Array(m.Var,2,value=1,lb=0,ub=50)
puree=100; cutlet=120
m.Equation(puree*x+cutlet*y==1500)
m.Maximize(m.min3(x,y))
m.solve(disp=False)
print(x.value[0],y.value[0])
```

The `m.min2()` function uses complementarity constraints while the `m.min3()` function uses a binary variable. The binary variable requires that this problem is solved with either a Mixed Integer Linear Programming (MILP) solver or Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming (MINLP) solver. Gekko automatically selects `m.options.SOLVER=1` when you use `m.min3()`. This produces the solution:

```
6.8181818182
6.8181818182
```

More information on `m.min2()` is [available here](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Apps/MpecExamples).